# JavaFX Webview: addEventListener for clicks NOT on an hyperlink?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

In WebView, is there a way to execute a function for any click NOT on an given hyperlink?

I tried to add an event handler on the WebView to always execute the function, and then add an event listener to hyperlinks in an attempt to consume the event. However, `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` don't actually stop the event, so the function is still executed when an hyperlink is clicked.

In this example, the message is still printed when an hyperlink is clicked:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Setup the WebView
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        String content = "<br>some text<br> a link: <a href='www.google.com'>google</a></body>";
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(content);

        // Add the hyperlink listener
        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                (o, old, state) -> {
                    if (state != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) { return; }

                    // Create the event listener
                    EventListener listenerA = event -> {
                        System.out.println("Attempting to block the click");
                        // Doesn't actually block the click
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    };

                    Document doc = webView.getEngine().getDocument();
                    // Add event handler to <a> hyperlinks.
                    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                        EventTarget hyperlink = (EventTarget) nodeList.item(i);
                        hyperlink.addEventListener("click", listenerA, true);
                    }
                });
        // Add the click listener
        webView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                event -> System.out.println("I want this to be printed only when a click occurs outside an hyperlink"));

        // Setup the scene
        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this because I use WebView as a transparent overlay for my Swing UI; I have clicks forwarded to the Swing components but I want to not forward clicks to Swing if the user clicks on an overlay hyperlink.

Comment: You mean [`Event#consume()`](http://docs.52im.net/extend/docs/api/javafx-8u51/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--)?

Comment: @M. S. I would, except consume() is not available for [org.w3c.dom.events.Event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/Event.html).